# Facebook sharer only pulling 3 images

Tags: html, facebook, sharing

I am using the facebook sharer on a webpage with a bunch of images of various aspect ratios.  I'm defining `og:image` meta tags for a number of the images (typically 7-10) and everything always looks good in the [debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), however all new pages and any old page that I refresh with the debugger only show 3 images in the share popup.  This is consistently happening and doesn't seem related to the size or content of the images.  The fact that it's always  returning 3 makes me think it's a fb issue.  Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Can you post a link to one of the URLs?

Comment: I get a whole bunch of images with the debugger... 22 to be exact. But still only 3 on FB... Smells to me like a caching issue on FB's side..

Comment: How long ago did the page change? Facebook usually refreshes the cached version when an admin uses the debugger.

Comment: I ran that page through the debugger right before posting the link.  I just sent the link around the office and everyone here sees 3 images.  This is really weird

Comment: Oh - also there is some errors that the debugger is complaining about. Specifically some images sizes.. Could it be possible that only 3 of the images are eligible?

Comment: I saw a couple warnings, but there are many images that don't fit the warning and are not displayed.  It's consistently happening on many pages.  exactly 3 available

Comment: I'd say you should give it some time to see if FB drops it's cached version. Failing that, perhaps a bug report it needed.

Comment: I found this issue raised in facebook bug tool. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/144855142354849?browse=search_5179340841eb40432072733 It still doesn't have any solution, but maybe we get an answer over there.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem with Facebook before as well. Sometimes, even without the proper error/warning message, you need a larger version of your image to set as the default. While Facebook's warning messages in debugger state 200x200 as a minimum size, I generally stick to no less than 600x300 whenever possible. Also keep aspect ratio in mind, and, as others have stated, you may need to file a bug report after all.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that if you set your og:type to "article" Facebook will pull up to 3 images.

As a possible solution you can change the og:type to "website" or "product", this way Facebook will pull more images.

Comment: We were already using website.  Maybe there's some connection here, since it was exactly 3 in all cases.  Anyways, we gave up and included exactly 3 images on the pages I got the request about - we were trying to specifically include one main image and didn't care as much about the others, so the way facebook was discarding images randomly meant our main image was frequently dropped in favor of 3 others